# Hyper V fail over cluster

Tags: hyper-v, cluster, failover

I have two Hyper V host. One with Intel adapter and other with Broadcom. Is this configuration supported.?
While running validation test I am getting error message.

Node 'HOST1.poc.lab' is missing a virtual Ethernet switch 'Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection - Virtual Switch' that is present on at least one other node. Either remove the virtual Ethernet switch from all nodes or ensure that it is present on all nodes.
Node 'HOST2.poc.lab' is missing a virtual Ethernet switch 'Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet - Virtual Switch' that is present on at least one other node. Either remove the virtual Ethernet switch from all nodes or ensure that it is present on all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the same names for virtual switches. It might help here. If not - please let me know, we'll find out what's wrong.